# Is there a way to create directional light in 2D?

Tags: opengl-es, processing, webgl, p5.js

In processing there is a function that creates directional light in 3D. But i wanna create the same effect in 2D. I think i need a vector and color info so i can create a shadow effect on a image.

Like this: [image: https://imgur.com/a/wDEJWkT]

The mouse becomes a point of light and when it moves around it changes the image creating a shadow effect on it.

I can't use function that are 3D like pointLight or directionalLight so any ideas where should i start?

Comment: What do you mean you can't use  a 3D like pointlight or directional light? The normal way to do this is to put a normal map on plane and then just use a standard 3D pointlight or directional light. [example](https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/2d/lighting-with-normal-maps/), and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=2d+normal+map&oq=2d+normal+map)